# Center display-inblock

Tags: menu, navigation, css

On ([my site](http://floor123test.weebly.com)) I would like to place the menubar in the center of the page.
Here the code of my menubar:

```
#navigation {
    padding-bottom: auto;
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    border: 0px solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping me! :)

Comment: inline-block element can be centered with tex-align set on parent. :) 
`.bg-wrapper {
text-align:center;
}`

Comment: `padding-bottom: auto;`?

Comment: You need to post all relevant code (NOT a live site as this changes for users down the road, and they wont benefit from your question), and possibly a JSFiddle.  This code isn't all of the styling for your nav and you don't add the nav code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `width: 100%;` to your `#navigation` for a full-wdith centered menu.

---

Or change the `display` to `block` for a centered menu without a full-width background.

---

If you want to keep the yellow line under, add a 1px bottom margin. This will shift the rest one pixel lower and it will reveal a yellow line.

```
margin-bottom: 1px
```

Working JSFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/qwnwkp7u/2/

Comment: Yes, it worked for me, but the menubar becomes so a lot bigger than needed, which I won't prefer..

Comment: I have edited my answer with two approaches, one with a full width background, and one without that would then give you a small menu that is just wide as needed :)

Comment: but I want to keep the tiny yellow line under the menu bar (which one I would like to increase), when I use display: block; , I lose that little line.

Comment: Ok ok then add this `margin-bottom: 1px` to your CSS code. I have updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Switch display: inline-block; to display: block;

Comment: but I want to keep the tiny yellow line under the menu bar (which one I would like to increase), when I use display: block; , I lose that little line.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to understand something about block and inline-block elements.

Block elements , if sized and smaller than page/container can basicly; be centered with margin:auto;.

Inline-block element behaves like text and can follow text-align value.

To center your menu , you have then 2 options:
 `margin:auto;` with a block formating, you need then just to remove your inline-block display  wich does:

```
#navigation {
padding-bottom: auto;
width: 960px;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
overflow: hidden;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
background-color: #DDDDDD;
border: 0px solid;
border-radius: 15px;
color: #000000;
}
```

or 
`text-align:center;` from its parent if as an inline boxe. Wich would be here :

```
.bg-wrapper {
text-align:center;
}
```

If inline-block was here used to trigger some special layout , like to hold floatting elements, you could here turn `display:block` into `display:table;`.

doei